# SQL Trigger not executing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple SQL Trigger that I cannot get to work.  Code is below.  All I am trying to do is have the trigger run if the "VendID" column is updated in Table1.  The Trigger should write a hardcoded record to the Inventory table as shown below, but it is not doing this.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Table1_VendorID_modified]
   ON  [dbo].[Table1]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

        IF (UPDATE(VendID))
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO database1.dbo.Inventory
    (
        ClassID
        , Crtd_User
        , LUpd_DateTime
        , LUpd_User
        , VendId
    ) 
    SELECT '1', 'username', '9/10/2014', 'user1', '123456ABCDEF'
END
```

Comment: You're missing an `END` after your SELECT statement.  Your IF statement has a BEGIN with no END.

Comment: After you fix the missing end you might want to remove the quotes on 1 if ClassID is the numeric type.Also is `IF (UPDATE(VendID)`) valid sql syntax?

Comment: What does "cannot get to work" mean? Do you get an error message when trying to create the trigger? If so, what is it? Is it solved by the obvious typo (missing `END`)?

Comment: There is a second END statement at the conclusion of this code bloack that I forgot to include.  By not working I mean there is no error message, the INSERT statement simply does not execute as it should

Comment: The ClassID field is indeed a char(10) field.  However, LUpd_DateTime is a datetime type.  Could this be the issue for inserting?

Comment: The INSERT INTO statement is not the issue.  I just executed that statement itself and it inserted the row correctly.  The issue has to be in the IF (UPDATE(VendID)) part

Comment: Does `database1.dbo.Inventory` have unique constraints or primary keys?  Does the insert statement you have work after multiple executions?

Comment: Two traps for the unwary. First, in SQL Server, the trigger is run once per update statement - not once per row. Secondly, the UPDATE() function tells you only that the column was mentioned in the SET clause of the UPDATE statement. It does *not* tell you whether the new value was different to the old value of the column.

Comment: There is no data currently in the Inventory table and no primary key contraints that would prevent a row from being inserted.

Comment: @digital that link is MySql. SQL Server does not need or even accept `end if`

Comment: Try changing the column in update,it looks to me as a identity column so it might not count as an update.Just a wild guess.Also try to move IF(UPDATE)... after AS

Comment: @MartinSmith  Sorry, misread and thought this was a mysql question.

Comment: @Mihai The IF (UPDATE) statement does come after the AS statement, as seen above.  or did you mean move IF (UPDATE) before the AS statement?

Comment: I mean immediately after AS. `AS IF (UPDATE(VendID)) BEGIN....`